# How to display an image in a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, tooltip

I'm trying to display an icon in a `Qt` application. Problem is, I don't know how to do it. I've read multiple forums, the `Qt documentation`, but I'm still confuse on how to do it.

What I want to acheive is an icon that when you keep your cursor on, it display a toolTip. I'm creating a class for it because my program will need a few of these.

What you got to know:

-My image is in a different folder

-This class is only used to display an icon/image and a toolTip.

-Here is the image i want to display
[image: Interrogation]

This is what i got so far, I don't even know if I'm heading in the good direction.

```
InformationIcon::InformationIcon(QString toolTipInformation){
    this->setMask(":\img\Interrogation.png");
    this->setToolTip(toolTipInformation);
    this->setToolTipDuration(5000);
    this->show()
}
```

I'd like some information on why you do it this way. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn.

Thanks

Comment: In order to obtain images in such format as `:\img\Interrogation.png` you need to involve resource file. Please refer to `The Qt Resource System`.

Comment: '\i' is undefined char (one, not two as you think). If you want a backslash in any string in code you should type '\\', not '\'. Also, for Qt resource path you should use slash, not backslash (':/img/bla.png')

Comment: Thanks. I'll change my path and I'll refer to Qt Ressource System.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QLabel to display an image with QLabel::pixmap

Comment: Yeah but how, I don't understand how to do it. Does my object has to be a QLabel? or do I just create an object of a QLabel and use the show() function?

Comment: you need just place QLabel on your form and pass some path to the image. I don't know how do you access your form, may be in this way:

    `ui->label1->setPixmap(":/img/Interrogation.png");`

Answer (score 0):

```
QLabel * widget_to_show_image_on = new QLabel(this);

// Add to layout

widget_to_show_image_on->setPixmap(QPixmap(path_to_pixmap));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InformationIcon::InformationIcon(QString toolTipInformation, int toolTipTimeDuration){
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/Interrogation.png"));
    this->setToolTip(toolTipInformation);
    this->setToolTipDuration(toolTipTimeDuration);
}
```

This seems to work fine. The difference is that it herits from QLabel instead of QWidget.

Thanks for the help though